# sscanf ignoring "&" and scanning past where it is supposed to

Tags: html, c++, scanf, cgi

I am using a `.cpp` file I compiled to run as a `.cgi` file on my website, receiving data from a web form, which it then runs `sscanf()` on to get the data extracted from the formatting that was sent in.

However, when the data is passed in and parsed, the first string takes all of the input past where it is supposed to.

My CPP file:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
  printf("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=us-ascii\n\n");
  printf("Hello world\n\n");
  char* data;
  data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");

  char name [50];
  int port;
  int id;
  char config[50];
  sscanf(data, "Name=%s&Port=%d&ID=%d&Config=%s", &name, &port, &id, &config);
  printf("%s", name);
  return 0;
}
```

The `data` variable is `Name=ss&Port=8081&ID=0&Config=testconfig`.

My expected output:

```
Hello world

ss
```

My actual output:

```
Hello world

ss&Port=8081&ID=0&Config=testconfig
```

Any ideas why it ignores the `&` and continues putting all the data into that variable?

So far, I have tried changing the data types of both `data` and `name` to `std::string`, but still had no luck.

Comment: The `%s` specifier stops only when a whitespace character is found. Maybe that's your problem?

Comment: Oh, and also, if you are using this program, to parse input from a web form, you should maybe take SOME security precautions and use `%49s`, since you have strings 50 characters long.

Comment: This appears to be straight C code rather than C++, aside from including `<string>` which is never used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%s` is greedy. Since you are not telling it where to stop, it will just keep grabbing input until either a whitespace character or the null terminator is reached (which in your case is the latter).

Use `%[^&]` instead. `%[]` is like `%s` except that it will only grab or ignore just the characters you specify. This way, you can tell `scanf()` to stop reading input when the `&` character is reached.

Either way, you should always specify buffer widths to avoid overflows.

Try this:

```
sscanf(data, "Name=%49[^&]&Port=%d&ID=%d&Config=%49s", &name, &port, &id, &config);
```